# Parsing a CSV of Nested JSONs

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a CSV of JSON files, directly from a database. Each JSON has nested JSONs, and I am struggling to parse this CSV and keep each JSON intact (i.e., still nested). Ideally I want to return a Pandas Series/DataFrame object where each row is the highest level of these nested JSONS.

The default `pandas.read_csv('filepath.csv')` doesn't work. I've tried replacing the delimiter with other characters, but still have the same issue.

I'm unsure of how best to proceed. I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please produce a minimal, reproducible example so we can help. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you include part of your json in here? Also, point out which column you need in dataframe

Comment: We definitely need a sample of the data if you want further assistance. Are you sure the file is not JSONL (JSONLines)?  In that case you can simply read it in using `pd.read_json('filepath.csv', lines=True)`.